# Filter array_values in javascript and stored it in new variable

Tags: javascript, mysql, loops, vue.js, console

How to filter last_login = null and get the array_values?

```js
 //   for(let y=0; y<this.searchLogin.length; y++ ){
 //      for(let i=0; i<this.list.length; i++){
 //         if(this.list[y].last_login == null ){
 //           this.retval.push(this.newval[i])
 //            } else {
 //             null
 //             }
 //        }
 //    }

 //   this.newval = []
 //    this.newval = this.retval
 //    this.retval = []
```

Updated:

```js
var output = [];
  for (var i=0; i < this.list.length ; ++i){
    for(let i=0; i<this.list.length; i++){
      if(this.list[y].profile.last_login == null ){
        output.push(this.list[i]);
      return output;
    }
  }
}
```

console.log('this is list',this.list) output:

[image: console.log('this is list',this.list)]

Comment: paste your JSON data rather attaching the screenshots. and try using [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: What is not working with your code? Can you give us a [mcve] of it running?

Answer (score 0):

It's really difficult to understand what's going on with the limited information you've provided, but it might be that you're assigning `this.retval` to `this.newval` and then emptying `this.retval`.  Assuming you're returning `this.newval` after that might be an isuse.  Arrays are reference values in Javascript so you've essentially set you're `this.newval` to an empty array as well.  In Javascript it's not 100% clear at first glance when something is a reference so when you have issues with values changing when you don't want them to it's best to research if that might be the case.